# Suspend spring service while it is initializing

Tags: java, spring, server, jersey, backend

I have a service that is dependent on several resources.
This service has a initialization logic that checks if these resources are up and running, and starts / stops the service accordingly.

The problem is, that other services are addressing my services via REST while it is loading. It then tries to reply (in a different thread), and when it does, it tries to connects to one of the not-yet-available resources and crashes.

Is there a way to 'lock' the service while it is loading so that any request coming to it from the outside will return 'Service not available' while it is in its loading process?

There are many requests to the service and I don't wan't to add a 'check resource status' logic to every method that handles an HTTP request. I want to be able to block all requests and the unblock them when all resources are up.

Any help will be great. (I'm not very familiar with Spring yet).

Comment: Is it possible for you to NOT spawn REST service thread unless and until your initialization logic return true or false?

Comment: Unfortunately at the correct moment, no.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming these resources get initialised asynchronously, you can write a `Filter` or an `Interceptor` to filter the request and retuen 503 if the resources are not loaded.

[Here's](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/how-to-register-a-servlet-filter-in-spring-mvc/) an example of how to configure a filter. You can even write an Interceptor if you want to do handle/intercept the requests at resource level (example [here](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-handler-interceptors-example/)), however, as you want to filter all the incoming requests, I would recommend going ahead with `Filter`.